# xstring fails to compare text containing \\

Tags: xstring

Using xstring in order to compare text containing `\\` produces a compilation error. Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{xstring}
\makeatletter
\def\Example#1{\def\@Example{#1}}
\def\printExample{\@Example}
\makeatother
\Example{not \\ void}
\AtBeginDocument{
\begin{titlepage}
\centering
\IfStrEq{}{\printExample}
    {void}
    {\printExample}
\end{titlepage}
}
\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

The first error message is:

> ! Undefined control sequence.
>   \  ->\let \reserved@e 
>                          \relax \let \reserved@f \relax @ifstar {\let \reserv...
>   l.15 \begin{document}

The `\Example` command defined here should accept `\\`. How can I get this working? The solution should take into account that the (La)TeX distribution version used here is the one included in Linux Mint 18.3, i.e. TeX Live 2017/Debian, which cannot be changed.

Comment: What is the expected output. You could try using `\noexpandarg`, but I am not sure what the code is supposed to do.

Comment: If you are just testing whether a macro is empty or not, then the void tests from `etoolbox` might be better, that is what I normally use. But as Peter mentions, it is not quite clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: It works with `xifthen` using this test: `\ifthenelse{\equal{\printExample}{}}{void}{\printExample}`

Comment: Various tests from `etoolbox` (`\ifdefvoid`, `\ifstrempty` or `\ifblank`) do not work with TeX Live 2017/Debian (but they work for current TeX Live). Command `\ifthenelse` from `xifthen` works well, indeed (even if, from a "logical" perspective, I would expect a command whose argument is directly a string, not a boolean). Can someone explain why `\\ ` breaks `\IfStrEq` and if there is a way (or not) to use it?

Comment: I added `\centering` in environment `titlepage` because it causes an error (_! Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line …_) when `\ifthenelse` test is used. An other error is raised with `center` environment (_! Use of \@item doesn't match its definition._). In both cases, one needs to use `\protect\\ ` in order to get it working as expected.

Answer (score 4):

If you need only a test for an empty argument you can use `\ifx`:

```
\documentclass{report}
\makeatletter
\def\Example#1{\def\@Example{#1}}
\def\printExample{\@Example}
\makeatother
\Example{}
\AtBeginDocument{%
    \begin{titlepage}
        \expandafter\ifx\printExample\empty
        void\else\printExample\fi
    \end{titlepage}
}
\begin{document}

\Example{not \\ void}
\expandafter\ifx\printExample\empty
void\else\printExample\fi

\end{document}
```

Comment: This might be an option. Is it possible to write a 3-parameter command, e.g. `\ifstringempty`, from the `\expandafter` to `\fi` code, where #1 would be the tested string command (here `\printExample`), #2 for true (here "void"), and #3 for false (here the second `\printExample`), in order to simplify the code? I tried `\newcommand{\ifstringempty}[3]{\expandafter\ifx#1\empty
        #2\else#3\fi}`, without success.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have other macros such as `\Example` and `\printExample`.

You can define a macro that does the work getting as input the desired storage bin.

```latex
\documentclass{report}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\void@or@print}[1]{%
  \if\relax\detokenize\expandafter{#1}\relax
    void%
  \else
    #1%
  \fi
}

\def\printExample{\void@or@print{\@Example}}
\def\Example#1{\def\@Example{#1}}
\Example{} % initialize

\makeatother

\Example{not \\ void}

\AtBeginDocument{
\begin{titlepage}
\centering
\printExample
\end{titlepage}
}

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

A more general implementation:

```latex
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\print@conditionally}[3]{%
  \if\relax\detokenize\expandafter{#1}\relax
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
  {#2}{#3}%
}

\def\printExample{\print@conditionally{\@Example}{void}{\@Example}}
\def\Example#1{\def\@Example{#1}}
\Example{} % initialize

\makeatother
```

Comment: Yes, there are few other macros as `\Example`, that should be filled by the template's user (while `\printExample`'s are in some way hidden). But the true/false outputs depend on the macro, i.e., some show a "should-be-filled-message" in the PDF documents if empty, other are optional, and when correctly filled their formattings mostly differ. This is why I need a real if-then-else statement.

Comment: @JérômeChampavère I added a more general implementation